# cURL Session Issue in trying to auto-login to Wordpress from Magento

Tags: php, wordpress, magento, php-curl

In My Local, I create a file in my Magento root file for cURL Login to my WordPress site which is placed in the same Magento root folder.

I can log in and redirect the user dashboard to the WordPress site successfully, but the issue is I can only login this one page - if I click any other option in the user dashboard it asks me to log in.

```html
<?php
require_once('app/Mage.php');
umask(0);
Mage::app('default');

function curl_get_wp_login( $login_user, $login_pass, $login_url, $visit_url, $http_agent, $cookie_file ){
    if( !function_exists( 'curl_init' ) || ! function_exists( 'curl_exec' )){
    $m = "cUrl is not vailable in you PHP server.";
    echo $m;
    }
    // Preparing postdata for wordpress login
    $data = "log=". $login_user ."&pwd=" . $login_pass . "&wp-submit=Log%20In&redirect_to=" . $visit_url . "&testcookie=1";

    //$data = "username=". $login_user ."&password=" . $login_pass . "&woocommerce-login-nonce=5661edfebd&_wp_http_referer=" . $visit_url . "&login=Log+in";

    //echo 'data : '.$data; exit;
    // Intialize cURL
    $ch = curl_init();
    // Url to use
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $login_url );
    // Set the cookies for the login in a cookie file.
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file );
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, "cookiename=0");
    //SET HEADER
    $headers = array(
       "Cookie: wordpress_test_cookie=WP+Cookie+check"
    );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    //curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, 'read_header');
    // Set SSL to false
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
    // User agent
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $http_agent );
    // Maximum time cURL will wait for get response. in seconds
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60 );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1 );
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
    // Return or echo the execution
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
    // Set Http referer.
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $login_url );
    // Post fields to the login url
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    // Save the return in a variable
    $content = curl_exec ($ch);
    'Error Details: ' . curl_error($ch);
    curl_close( $ch );
    echo $content;
    
    //header('location: http://127.0.0.1/chankya_dev/wordpress/my-account/');
    //die();
}

/*$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "wordpress_db";

// Create connection
$conn= mysqli_connect($servername,$username,$password,$dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
  die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
echo "Connected Successfully.";

$sql = "SELECT ID, user_login, user_pass, user_nicename, user_email, user_url, user_registered, user_activation_key, user_activation_key, display_name FROM wp_users";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  // output data of each row

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<br /> id: " . $row["ID"]."<br /> User Name: " . $row["user_login"]."<br /> Password: " . $row["user_pass"];
    }
} else {
  echo "0 results";
}

 $conn->close();

exit;*/
// Username for login
$login_user = "bhavin";
$login_pass = "bhavin@123";
//$login_url = "http://wp.local.com/wp-login.php";
$login_url = "http://127.0.0.1/chankya_dev/wordpress/wp-login.php";
//$visit_url = urlencode('http://wp.local.com/wp-admin');
//$visit_url = urlencode('http://127.0.0.1/chankya_dev/wordpress/wp-admin/');
$visit_url = urlencode('http://127.0.0.1/chankya_dev/wordpress/my-account/');
//$cookie_file = "/cookie.txt";
$cookie_file = "C:/xampp/htdocs/chankya_dev/cookie.txt";
//$cookie_file = Mage::getBaseDir()."cookie.txt";
$http_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6";

/*echo 'File Dir : '.Mage::getBaseDir()."/cookie.txt";
echo '<br />';
echo 'File Path :- '.$cookie_file; exit;*/

curl_get_wp_login( $login_user, $login_pass, $login_url, $visit_url, $http_agent, $cookie_file);
```

Can anyone help me to solved my issue?

Basically I want auto-login when I am login into Magento